# Python RegEx Search for finding variable value from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a HTML string coming from server. I would like to fetch right side of the token.

```
vega.csrfToken = "019387r218r72r696r826r87469786487";
```

I am using `.*csrfToken[\s="\w]+` to match entire line with

```
csrfToken =  re.search('.*csrfToken[\s="\w]+', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Whereas certain regex tester portal works, Python fails to find the line. 
What are the changes required to match the line? What would be the best way to get only the RHS to = in the line.

Comment: Try this `r'.*csrfToken\s=\s"(\w+)"'`.

Comment: You may need to escape the quote in your regex.

Comment: That error is not because of the regex maybe you have a syntax error in the rest of your code.

Comment: @Kasramvd I am still not getting complete String

Comment: @Kasramvd ehh Yes. I quickly realized that. Sorry for that silly stuff.

Comment: The `csrfToken.group(0)` will give you the entire match and `csrfToken.group(1)` will give you the expected part.

Comment: @Kasramvd Oh Yes. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it as a right one? BTW, can you plz explain issue with my regex? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use a `r` prefix for your regex because it needs to get interpreted as a raw string. Secondly the part `[\s="\w]+` will match any combination of whitespace, equal sign, double quote and word character with length 1 or more which wont give you the exact part your want. Also you need to use capture grouping in order to get the expected part.

So you can simply use following regex:

```
csrfToken =  re.search(r'.*csrfToken\s=\s"(\w+)"', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

And get the expected part using `csrfToken.group(1)`